# Problem with fraction and align environment - "&" symbol

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am new in LaTeX, thus I need your help.

I want to align the `\leq` symbol under the `+` symbol. The problem is that the `+` symbol is contained inside a fraction, therefore, the `\begin{aligned}--\end{aligned}` environment, does not allow me to insert the `&` symbol inside this certain fraction.

How can I achieve this without having any problems?

An example:

```
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\frac{2x}{y **&+** z}}+\sqrt{\frac{2y}{z+x}}+\sqrt{\frac{2z}{x+y}}\\
&\leq 3.
\end{aligned}$
```

P.S I have searched the site but I haven't found anything similar with my problem. (maybe I am not searching, right?)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend a different approach and that is to use an `\hphantom` to insert the appropriate amount of horizontal space:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `\hphantom` instead of `\phantom` as I did not want the vertical size of `\sqrt{{\frac{2x}{y **}}}` to affect the second row.
- Alignment points located inside other terms such as `\sqrt` and `frac` are not usually this easy to do, and David's solution was quite clever in moving it outside and inserting a negative `\hspace`.  I personally would never have thought of that as I tend to think of alignment form the left moving towards the right.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{\frac{2x}{y **+** z}}+\sqrt{\frac{2y}{z+x}}+\sqrt{\frac{2z}{x+y}}\\
&\hphantom{\sqrt{{\frac{2x}{y **}}}}\leq 3.
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have some multline equation to typeset and you don't align globally by `=` or `\leq`, I would suggest you to try:

```
\begin{multline}
  f/i/r/s/t + l/i/n/e
\\
  \leq s/e/c/o/n/d + l/i/n/e
.\end{multline}
```

And surely you should use proper displayed equation and *never ever do* `$\displaystyle`. The env `multline` is provided by the package `amsmath` and you do not put it inside another environment (it is similar to `equation`). As well, it has a starred variant `multline*` that suppresses the numbering.

Comment: @George, while the other two answers do what you asked, you should accept this one, you don't need alignment here.

Answer (score 4):

This is a seriously odd place to align, what mathematical meaning do you mean to convey by aligning the inequality with the `+` in the subterm?

However:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\mlength

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\mlength}{$+**z$}
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\frac{2x}{y **+** z}}&+\sqrt{\frac{2y}{z+x}}+\sqrt{\frac{2z}{x+y}}\\
&\hspace{-\mlength}\leq 3.
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for you quick response. Well, I have some big Inequality expressions, and when I align them to center I must break them in 2 lines. But there is a problem at this point, since they exceed the paper size.

Comment: Breaking into multiple lines is fine but _aligning_ the <= with a + in a subterm makes no mathematical sense, the alignment is intended to align matching operators